# Youtube/Netflix randomlly pauses and displays pause icon after rooting/deleting apps

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, root-access, samsung-galaxy-s-4, youtube, att

I fear I may have damaged my samsumg galaxy s4 android 5.0 phone by rooting and deleting some unwanted bloatware. Now when I am watching youtube/netflix at random intervals (2-10 minutes) it will pause and I have to hit the play button in the middle of the screen to continue to watch the video. This is extremely annoying if I have it a couple feet away playing a video or audio. Is there a way I can fix my stupidity by restoring the apps on my phone? Is there a fix for netflix/youtube randomly pausing? Thanks.

Comment: Just commenting to say that this happens for me as well on my rooted Sony Xperia E3 Kitkat which is also rooted. This used to happen before I rooted though.

Comment: Did you not make a backup before rooting? If so, just restore from there.. :)

Comment: Have you enabled Smart Pause? That automatically pauses the video if you look away. (Or cover the front camera).

Comment: @MichaelNancarrow No I did not sadly. I was new at this and didn't realize the consequences of my actions. Is there no other way to repair the specific modules that i uninstalled?

Comment: @SuperThomasLab I believe I did, that was a suggestion i saw elsewhere, did not help. I had it on before I rooted and deleted some software and it worked great in the same environment I am using it now.

Comment: Then I guess you can just reflash your firmware. You can find the correct firmware on http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/. This will not wipe `/data`, but make a backup just in case.

Answer (score 1):

## The problem may be that Smart Pause is not being smart

In the gesture settings menu see if smart pause is enabled, and disable it. Smart Pause is a feature that, using the front facing camera, recognizes (or tries to) when you look away and pauses your video automatically. This would be my first guess at this problem, with the given information.

Comment: Turned this off but I still get the issue. Seriously considering reinstalling the firmware/os but afraid of doing more damage.